# Auto screenshot capture tool for linux

Tags: software-recommendation, screenshot

I use zscreen in windows to capture my screen every 2 minute and save them on local file system with date time label. Is there any tool or script to doing this on linux Ubuntu?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use scrot and put it in /etc/crontab
add this to /etc/crontab

```
*/2 * * * * <username> scrot
```

For that you need scrot, which you can install like this:

```
sudo apt-get install scrot
```

You can also give scrot the following argument to move images to your Pictures directory

```
scrot '%Y-%m-%d_$wx$h_scrot.png' -e 'mv $f ~/Pictures/'
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. If i want to use scrot only when i want crontab isn't true manner for this issue. I use script for this issue `while true; do scrot & sleep 2; done` but when i use this script it's sleep influence on all system like in typing and cause delay in typing. How can i fix this issue?

Comment: When scrot takes a screenshot, its sound beeb, how silent this?